# How do I convert 120FPS video from the iPhone 5s to 60FPS?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, video

When I shoot 120FPS video on the iPhone 5s, I can easily export it as a 30FPS video, slowed down four times. But I want to export it as a 60FPS video, slowed down twice.

Ideally, I'd like to do this without transcoding the video (because that reduces quality and increases file size), but merely having an app change the fields in the header to say that rather than playing for 1 minute at 120FPS, this video should play for 2 minutes at 60FPS.

I'm looking for:

- A Mac app, but if that's not possible, an iPhone app will do.
- A less expensive ($20) or free app.
- A GUI app, rather than a command line one.

I have iMovie 10, iPhoto 11, Picasa and Lightroom 5, but none of them seem to have this function. iMovie 10 can only export a 30FPS video, not a 60FPS one.

Is there any software that does this?

Comment: Recording at 60fps will help you out? Or do you want to "downgrade them"?

Comment: @Bmike, please don't edit the question in a way that changes the meaning for example, by saying that I'm looking for an app that does this one task well.

Comment: ... or by saying that I prefer tools that run ONLY on the command-line, because that implies tools that can be invoked from the command-line AND via a GUI are okay. That's not what I asked.

Comment: @Robuust The iPhone 5s can't shoot video at 60FPS. Besides, I want video that's slowed down twice, as I said. Even if the iPhone could shoot at 60FPS, that video would run at 100% speed, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Roll back my edit. I was trying to keep it from being closed as shopping. It's a good question - I wanted it to avoid potential down votes and was trying to help. Thanks so much for fixing the edit and letting me know which edits weren't an improvement.

Comment: @KartickVaddadi The edit didn't change the question actually. The point remained the same.

Comment: @bmike thanks for your help. Robuust, let's agree to disagree, and focus on the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

Update2: Official Apple Support [iMovie (2013): Slow down and speed up clips](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14728?viewlocale=en_US):

```
Make a clip play more slowly
In the timeline, select the clip you want to slow down.

Choose Modify > Slow Motion, and choose a speed percentage from the submenu.
```

Update: Maybe i misunderstood the question, you just want to make it half the FPS without changing the play speed, right? iMovie 11 for Mac is supported to export 60 FPS videos:

```
So, here is what you have to do if you want to export a 60p movie made with your 60p footage :
- create a NTSC (29.97 fps) project in iMovie
- choose "export using quicktime" in the "Sharing" menu
- choose the correct codec settings (I choose a Quicktime movie with the H264 and AAC codecs, max quality, and recompress the movies with Handbrake afterwards)
- be sure to check the correct framerate (59.94 fps for my 2 cameras, I guess it should be pretty standard - you can always check it in the information window in Quicktime Player for a raw file from your camera)
- export and enjoy.
```

[Source](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19199608#19199608)

You can slow it down using iMovie on iOS:

[image]

Or you can use different applications for record, like [SloPro - 1000fps Slow Motion Video](http://clk.tradedoubler.com/click?p=211220&a=2100672&url=https://itunes.apple.com/hu/app/slopro-1000fps-slow-motion/id507232505?mt=8&uo=4&partnerId=2003).

Comment: What I'm looking for is a 1-minute 120FPS clip to end up as a 2-minute 60FPS clip. Things would happen at half the speed as they do in real life. "Export using QuickTime" has been removed in iMove 10. I doubt iMovie on iOS would work when the Mac version doesn't. If anything, the former is likely to have fewer options.

Comment: Then you could slow it down with the slider in iMovie for iOS, or use the iMovie 2013 for Mac like the official page said.

Comment: iMovie 2013 doesn't let you choose the frame rate to save at. That was part of the "Export using QuickTime" option that was removed. You can see the screenshot at https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/imovie/id408981434?mt=12&ls=1

Comment: What's with the tradedoubler redirect in the SloPro link? (http://clk.tradedoubler.com/click?p=211220&a=2100672&url=https://itunes.apple.com/hu/app/slopro-1000fps-slow-motion/id507232505?mt=8&uo=4&partnerId=2003)